# Remove decimal values in backend in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, backend

How to remove decimal from all numbers on the backend (admin)of Magento2? [image]

Currently, I use a module of lillik/price-decimal, but when I try to change the price of some product in some store at the advanced price, I lost the old price.

Comment: have you tried to run indexer after your change?

Comment: yes, i run indexer, clean and flush cache

Comment: though you are losing your old price values?

Comment: yes, because i have 2 store view and when i change the price in Special Price (Advanced Price) i lost the old price in Price input.